# android app with Google analytics on blackerry 10 devices

Tags: android, google-analytics, blackberry-10

I have an android app with Google-analytics integrated. Recently, i ported it for Blackberry10 devices and is currently there on both Playstore and Blackberry world. Now, how do i know from the analytics reports about the blackberry devices running my app. In the analytics report,for devices it shows a row in devices an "Not Set". I did not make any changes for porting my app to blackberry except the mandatory changes in the manifest.

Can anyone please give some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following would allow you to verify inside your app to see whether it's a BlackBerry or another Android device running your app (taken from [BB Developer site](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/apisupport/apisupport_inapp_payments_support.html)):

```
java.lang.System.getProperty("os.name").equals("qnx")
```

Unfortunately I am not sure what properties Google Analytics uses for its device information.